# fortran save integer

Tags: save, fortran, local-variables

I came across some code today that looked somewhat like this:

```
      subroutine foo()
      real blah
      integer bar,k,i,j,ll
      integer :: n_called=1
      save integer

      ...
      end
```

It seems like the intent here was probably `save n_called`, but is that even a valid statment to save all integers -- or is it implicitly declaring a variable named `integer` and saving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your 2nd interpretation, that is, the statement `save integer` implicitly declares a variable called `integer` and gives it the `save` attribute.  Fortran, of course, has no rule against using keywords as program entity names, though most sensible software developers do have such a rule.

If I try to compile your code snippet as you have presented it, my compiler (Intel Fortran) makes no complaint.  If I insert `implicit none` at the right place it reports the error

```
This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [INTEGER]
```

The other interpretation, that it gives the `save` attribute to all integer variables, seems at odds with the language standards and it's not a variation that I've ever come across.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too -- I should have thought about that silly `implicit none` test myself ... I guess I'm having an off day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The second interpretation is correct. Fortran has many keywords, `INTEGER` being one of them, but it has *no reserved words*, which means that keywords can be used as identifiers, though this is usually a terrible idea (but nevertheless it carries on to C# where one can prefix a keyword with `@` and use it as an identifier, right?)

The `SAVE` statement, even if it was intended for `n_called` is superficial. Fortran automatically saves all variables that have initialisers and that's why the code probably works as intended.

```
 integer :: n_called=1
```

Here `n_called` is automatically `SAVE`. This usually comes as a really bad surprise to C/C++ programmers forced to maintain/extend/create new Fortran code :)

Comment: Good point about `n_called` acquiring the save attribute implicitly.  As for your last point, well, when you hire a boy for a man's job ...

Comment: Yeah, I figured the part about the implicit save as well -- Is that actually guaranteed by the standard, or is it just a *very* common implementation detail?  -- Thinking about how in F77, `common` blocks weren't even guaranteed to be saved, it wouldn't surprise me if this was just a common thing that vendors do ...

Comment: @mgilson: I believe that the SAVE status of a variable which is initialised on declaration is processor-dependent in FORTRAN 77, but that the language standards since, and including, Fortran 90 have guaranteed this behaviour.

Comment: AFAIK standard FORTRAN 77 doesn't allow variable initialisation the way it is done in Fortran 90. One has to use the `DATA` statement to assign initial values and it is processor- (a.k.a. compiler-) dependent behaviour if the variable is automatically saved or not (i.e. if `DATA` results in automatic or static storage class). One should use `SAVE` to enforce static storage.

Comment: FORTRAN 77 vs Fortran 90 discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352741/fortran-assignment-on-declaration-and-save-attribute-gotcha