# Why is there an implied SAVE attribute in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

If I initialize a variable in a Fortran declaration statement, that variable implicitly receives a SAVE attribute and the initialization expression will only be executed once.

For example, the following program

```
program test
implicit none

    call foo()
    call foo()

contains

    subroutine foo ()
        integer :: i = 0

        i = i + 1
        write(*,*) i
    end subroutine foo
 end program test
```

will print

```
1
2
```

Since this is different in many other languages I was wondering why the Fortran standard committee chose this behavior?

Thanks a lot!
Mike

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352741/fortran-assignment-on-declaration-and-save-attribute-gotcha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is mainly due to historical reasons. Old compilers (Fortran IV(66) and before) were implemented to produce programs using mainly static memory. Old machines even didn't have any stack. Therefore the programs behave, as the variables were defined as `save`.

The predecessor of the variable initialization, the `DATA` statement, is more like defining an initial content of static memory (similar to the directives for the data segment in assembly), than the on call variable initialization you may know from C. The syntax became similar to the C variant later.

Comment: +1; whenever a convention doesn't make any sense at all, the answer is almost always "for historical reasons".   The second paragraph is most relevant here; initializing as `integer :: i = 0` is "like" the data statement which gave you static (and thus `save`) semantics.   For that (IMHO inadequate) reason, it's best to only use initialization like this for `parameters` to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the DATA statement. Since initialization expressions in declaration statements were relatively new, I thought it might have been another reason than history, but with the DATA statement in mind, this makes sense now.