# Fortran infinite loop when calling a function

Tags: fortran, infinite-loop, fortran95

Why am I in an infinite loop?

```
PROGRAM tayls
  USE kertoma
  USE tforexp
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: n= 5
  INTEGER :: i
  REAL :: x
  WRITE(*,*) "f1(x)= (e**x-1)/x"
  DO i=1,10
    x= 0.01*i
    WRITE(*,*)x, (taylexp(x,n)-1)/x
  END DO
END PROGRAM tayls
```

with

```
MODULE tforexp
  USE kertoma
  IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
      FUNCTION taylexp(x,ord)
        REAL :: taylexp, x, sum
        INTEGER :: ord, i
        sum= 1.0
        DO i=1,ord
          sum= sum+ x**i/fact(i)
        END DO
        taylexp= sum
      END FUNCTION taylexp
END MODULE tforexp
```

and

```
MODULE kertoma
  IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS
  FUNCTION fact(n)
    INTEGER :: fact,n,y=1
    DO WHILE (n>1)
      y= y*n
      n= n-1
    END DO
    fact = y
  END FUNCTION fact
END MODULE kertoma
```

The infinite loop starts right after the first print "f1(x)=...".
So I think it goes to infinite loop when calling the taylexp-function for the first time, but I don't understand why. 
I think it has got something to do with fortran using public variables, but I'm clueless how to consistently avoid this. 
First I tried to call the function without defining x, just using "0.01*i", and I thought maybe the problem was that this function used the same name for the dummy index, but it clearly it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is the problem, but note that `integer :: y=1` possibly [doesn't do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14565739/3157076) what you think it does.

Comment: Where is `taylerr` used? Why is it in the post then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is inside then function `fact(n)`:

```
n= n-1
```

changes the argument and, therefore, the loop counter `i` in `taylexp`. In your code `i` never exceeds `2`. I'm surprised the compiler didn't issue a warning (mine didn't either), because anything might happen in this case.

Better specify the `intent` of dummy arguments to avoid issues like this in the future:

```
  FUNCTION fact(n)
    integer,intent(in)  :: n
    INTEGER :: fact,nn,y

    y=1 ! Avoid the implicit save and assign variables separately
    nn=n
    DO WHILE (nn>1)
      y= y*nn
      nn= nn-1
    END DO
    fact = y
  END FUNCTION fact
```

Comment: Or possibly even `integer, intent(in), value :: n` and avoid the `nn`.

Comment: @francescalus Yeah, but I try to tackle one issue at a time ;-) (besides the implicit save, which should be banned from the Standard)

Answer (score 2):

With gfortran, it is possible to catch this error with
the -fcheck=all option:

```
$ gfortran -fcheck=all 1.f90 
$ ./a.out
 f1(x)= (e**x-1)/x
At line 22 of file 1.f90
Fortran runtime error: Loop variable has been modified
```