# Why is the counter variable unexpectedly increased in every subroutine call?

Tags: unicode, fortran, do-while, gfortran

[EDITORIAL:  I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565739/why-is-there-an-implied-save-attribute-in-fortran) but (while in hindsight it is ultimately related in the same way that every question here is related -- i.e., "Why do computers malfunction?") that answer is not the answer to my question.  That question is asking why a standards body designed a specific feature into the language.  And, the answer does not answer my question which is asking what have I missed in debugging this issue.]

**QUESTION**:  Why does the output from this Fortran program (*ExhaustiveListing.f08* + *unicodeSupport.f08*) shown below indicate that Fortran's DO WHILE has a major bug?

Here's the output followed by environment description and, finally, the source code of the two files in question:

## UNEXPECTED OUTPUT

> Hex is now: **2500H**.
>  
>   2500─
>   2501━
>   2502│
>   2503┃
>   2504┄
>   2505┅
>   2506┆
>   2507┇
>   2508┈
>   2509┉
>   250A┊
>   250B┋
>   250C┌
>   250D┍
>   250E┎
>   250F┏
>   Hex is now: **2510H**.
>   Hex is now: **2520H**.
>   Hex is now: **2530H**.
>   Hex is now: **2540H**.
>   Hex is now: **2550H**.
>   Hex is now: **2560H**.
>   Hex is now: **2570H**.
>   
>   RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 530ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

## EXPECTED OUTPUT

I expected to have 16 lines of detail between each "*Hex is now: **xxxxH***" line such as that printed between the **2500H** and **2510H** lines.

## PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS TO RESOLVE ISSUE

This program is my attempt to resolve an issue in a much larger project.  Having issues with that project (one such problem revolving around working with Unicode in Fortran), I created this project to isolate the Unicode issue.  At first, I had the trivial unicodeSupport module combined in the same file as the main program.  I removed it into its own file.  No, it should not matter and -- it did not affect the outcome.  This program is so plainly simple, I cannot see anything which I might be doing wrong.  Hence, my coming to SO in hopes that new eyes discover my blunder.  Else, it's time to file bug report with gFortran.

## ENVIRONMENT

The environment that I'm working in is:
**OS**:  *Ubuntu 17.10*
**IDE**: *Netbeans 8.2*
**JDK**: *Oracle (build 1.8.0_161-b12)*
**COMPILER**: *gFortran 7.2.0*
**COMPILER FLAGS**: *-std=f2008ts -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -frounding-math -fsignaling-nans*
**theGeeko61**: *4 decades developing in BASIC, Pascal, FORTRAN, C, Prolog, C++, Java, many others (sorted chronologically by the order in which I learned them)*

## ExhaustiveListing.f08

```
! File:   ExhaustiveListing.f08
! Author: geeko
!
! Created on March 25, 2018, 7:05 PM
!
! ☐ U2610 ☑ U2611 ☒ U2612
! Use above symbols for indicating items to
! be tested (☐), and items which have either
! passed (☑) or failed (☒) testing.
!
SUBROUTINE displayLine(hex)
    USE unicodeSupport
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: hex, counter=0, point

    DO WHILE (counter < 16)
        point = hex+counter
        WRITE(*,'(Z4.4,A)') point, CHAR(INT(point), ucs4)
        counter = counter+1
    END DO
END SUBROUTINE

PROGRAM ExhaustiveListingOfUnicodeBoxDrawingChars ! ☒
    USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
    USE unicodeSupport
!!!!!USE testUnicodeSupport         ! ☑
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER  :: hex

    open(output_unit, encoding='UTF-8')

    hex = 9472
    DO WHILE(hex<9600)
        PRINT '(A,Z4.4,A)', "Hex is now: ", hex, "H."
        CALL displayLine(hex)   ! ☒
        hex = hex+16
    END DO

!!!!CALL performTest()              ! ☑
END PROGRAM ExhaustiveListingOfUnicodeBoxDrawingChars
```

## unicodeSupport.f08

```
! File:   unicodeSupport.f08
! Author: geeko
!
! Created on March 25, 2018, 10:09 PM
!

MODULE unicodeSupport
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: ASCII = SELECTED_CHAR_KIND('ASCII')
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: UCS4 = SELECTED_CHAR_KIND('ISO_10646')
END MODULE unicodeSupport
```

Comment: In future, if you think you have found a "major bug" in Fortran please create as minimal example as possible which shows the same problem.

Comment: @francescalus:  That's what I had attempted to do... "minimal" is overly subjective... this was my minimal.. what would yours have looked like?  ;)  (A project with 1 file, in Fortran, is minimal, no?)

Comment: If you've seen some of the horrors I have to support you may see how non-minimal one source file can be :(.  But here, you can easily exhibit the same problem without any Unicode parts and the commented-out code.

Comment: @francescalus: You are right.. but there was no way (in advance) for me to know that it was NOT something to deal with Unicode.  I had specifically chosen Unicode issues in the mini-project because of all the warnings and hoops I've jumped through regarding gFortran's support thereof... e.g., when this project started, it was Fortran 95... we moved to Fortran 2008 precisely because of the Unicode improvement... which left me holding THAT as suspect.

Comment: @francescalus:  I had not thought that I had found a "major bug."  Don't know how you misunderstood that I had.

Comment: "Why does the output from this Fortran program .. shown below indicate that Fortran's DO WHILE has a major bug?"

Comment: Ugh. My bad. I had been so exhausted that I didn't realize I had done that. My apologies.

Comment: No worries.  I agree that "initialization implies save" is far from intuitive as a source of such problems (and if this were truly a poor question I'd have downvoted and not looked back).  Stripping down difficult cases to the minimum is a very valuable skill to acquire, though.

Comment: I agree that's a good skill to have. In the future, I'll at least get a good night's rest from problem code before posting on SO. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `counter` declared here

```
INTEGER :: hex, counter=0, point
```

possesses the `save` attribute by virtue of having its value defined on the initialization line.

The second time you enter the subroutine, its value will be 16 and hence there will be no loop.

Remove `=0` from the declaration line and write

```
counter = 0
```

afterwards.

Comment: Excellent vision you have.  I'm so glad it was my blunder.  I loathe filing bug reports.  :)