# Declaration and initialization of local variables in Fortran PURE FUNCTIONs

Tags: fortran

I have a function that looks like this:

```
PURE FUNCTION simulate(initial_state, time_specification)
        TYPE(ocean), INTENT(IN) :: initial_state
        TYPE(simulation_time), INTENT(IN) :: time_specification
        TYPE(ocean) :: simulate
        REAL :: t = 0.0      
        ! etc
END FUNCTION simulate
```

gfortran 4.8.1 informs me that

```
 REAL :: t = 0.0
                1
Error: Initialization of variable at (1) is not allowed in a PURE procedure
```

As I understand it, I should be able to use local variables within pure functions as long as they do not have the SAVE attribute.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352741/fortran-assignment-on-declaration-and-save-attribute-gotcha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under modern Fortran initialization implies `SAVE`.  From F2008 5.2.3

> Explicit initialization of a variable that is not in a common block implies the SAVE attribute, which may be confirmed by explicit specification.

You can use local variables, but just

```
real t
t = 0
```

which isn't initialization.

Comment: I think you mean `real :: t` but, thanks, that works!

Comment: Well, `::` is a style thing, except when it's required.  It isn't required in this case, but with initialization it is.  That said, some people prefer it each time for consistency.

Answer (score 7):

Beware! The initializing of variables during declaration *implies* the `save` attribute! This violates the `pure` condition. See [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#4) for details.

Better initialize the variable in your code later on...

Answer (score 1):

`REAL :: t = 0.0` is not `pure`, because it takes effect only the first time the function is called.