# In recursive Fortran subroutines, what is local to the individual call of the subroutine, and what is "global"?

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I have the following simple code (which is an example of something I am trying to do in a much more complicated code):

```
module linkmod

type link
  character(len=1) :: name
  type(link), pointer :: next => null()
end type link

contains

recursive subroutine tell_name(a)

type(link), target :: a
type(link), pointer :: b !b is useless, except to illustrate my point
integer :: num_outputs = 0

b => a
if (associated(b%next)) call tell_name(b%next)
print *, b%name
num_outputs = num_outputs + 1
print *, num_outputs

end subroutine tell_name

end module linkmod



program driver

use linkmod

type(link) :: a
type(link), pointer :: b

a%name = 'a'
allocate(a%next)
b => a%next
b%name='b'
allocate(b%next)
b => b%next
b%name = 'c'
allocate(b%next)
b => b%next
b%name = 'd'

call tell_name(a)

end program
```

I compile and run and get the following output:

```
 d
           1
 c
           2
 b
           3
 a
           4
```

Now, I get lucky here because this is the behavior I need, namely, when a call to `tell_name()` is exited, `b` in the calling instance has retained the value it had before the calling instance made the call, but `num_outputs` has been set to what it became *in the called instance*.  (Apologies if that was hard to read.  I tried my best there.)

The thing is, I don't really understand why things work this way.  Why do not *both* `b` and `num_outputs` retain the values they were assigned in the called instance?  Or, alternatively, why do they not *both* re-acquire the values they had in the calling instance, previous to the call?

What is the general rule here?  On the other hand, what if I wanted `num_outputs` in a calling instance to be unaffected by what happens in any called instance.  How would I arrange that?

(BTW, I wrote up an alternative version of the code where I replaced the `recursive subroutine` with a derived type procedure, called as

`call b%next%tell_name()`

I get the exact same behavior with it.)

Comment: You are aware that `num_outputs` has the `save` attribute and that `b` hasn't?

Comment: @francescalus  Well, honestly, no I guess not.  What makes them different?  How do I get rid of the `save` attribute if I need to?

Comment: The attribute [comes from the explicit initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352741/3157076) that happens in `integer :: num_outputs = 0`.  If you don't want to `save` it, don't initialize it (`integer num_output; ...; num_outputs=0`).

Comment: @francescalus  Well, learn something new every day ...  If you want to turn that into an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think closing as duplicate is  in order here.  will look for a suitable target.

Comment: I'm not convinced, @VladimirF, those are good duplicates targets.  Yes, "initialization implies save" is relevant, but an important further aspect of this question is "why is save a concern in _recursion_?".  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it changes much from the sequentisl execution in a loop. That's ehy I put the first one on top.